# How to get image src for qrcode frrom Node js. to React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, qr-code, body-parser, speakeasy

I am creating a QR code using React Js. and Node js. I dynamically get the qrcode data in the node js and want to enter the qrcode data as src in img tag which is in React Js. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Render your QR code like any other image whose URL is provided by the server.
You can send request to your server endpoint that gives your QR code as base64 string in response. Use that response to render your QR code in react with `<img src={response.Url} />`.

Comment: Can you please send me the code for the same as I dont have any idea on this

Comment: Actually I think it's against the community rules to code on behalf of other person :(